# Django form in another template

Tags: python, django, forms

New to Django, so please bear with me.

I've been fighting my way through the basic tutorial and documentation, but haven't found a satisfactory answer.

I have two models:

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('venue_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Space(models.Model):
    venue = models.ForeignKey('Venue', null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500) 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('space_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

A space belongs to a Venue. That's all fine.

What I want to do, is to create a Space from a VenueDetail view, and use that Venue as the foreign key (i.e no dropdown select on the Space ModelForm).

However I haven't got as far as trying to use the current venue instance in the space form (is that called context? Sorry, coming from Rails), as I'm stuck on the form redirecting part.

## views.py

```
class VenueDetail(FormView):
        model = Venue
        template_name = 'venues/detail.html'
        form_class = SpaceForm
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(VenueDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['form'] = SpaceForm
            return context

class SpaceCreate(CreateView):
        model = Space
        template_name = 'spaces/space_form.html'
        fields = '__all__'
```

## forms.py

```
class SpaceForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
                model = Space
                fields = '__all__'
```

## venue_urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', VenueListing.as_view(), name='venue_listing'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', VenueDetail.as_view(), name='venue_detail'),
    url(r'^create/$', VenueCreate.as_view(), name='venue_create')

]
```

## space_urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', SpaceListing.as_view(), name='space_listing'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', SpaceDetail.as_view(), name='space_detail'),
    url(r'^create/$', SpaceCreate.as_view(), name='space_create')
]
```

If the user is creating a space from a VenueDetail view, at the moment if they have any errors they are being given the form with errors showing, but at the standard SpacesCreate url. Obviously this is happening because the form POSTs to that URL which then calls SpaceCreate.as_view(). Really the user would expect to be at the same URL if the form failed. If the form validates fine, at the moment it goes to the correct place which is 'space/pk' of the created space, which is fairly standard.

Essentially what I'm asking is what is the Django way to include a form to create one model, on it's parents show/detail page with all the expected behaviour. Perhaps I should be using a custom View for this form action when on that Venue detail page? One that specifically redirects to the same Venue detail page if the form post doesn't validate?

Thanks in advance for any help

UPDATE

I used a normal function view in the end, and ended up with something like this:

## views.py

```
def new_space(request, venue_id):
        venue = Venue.objects.get(id = venue_id)
        context = {'form': SpaceForm, 'venue': venue}
        if request.method == 'POST':
                form = SpaceForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                        new_space = form.save(commit=False)
                        new_space.venue = venue
                        new_space.save()
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('space_listing'))
                else:
                        return render(request, 'spaces/new_space.html', {'form': form})
        else:
                form = SpaceForm()
        return render(request, 'spaces/new_space.html', context)
```

## urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<venue_id>[0-9]+)/new_space/$', views.new_space, name='new_space')
```

and all seems to be working well.

Comment: Forget about class-based views and just a write a plain old function view instead, it'll be easier.

Comment: I've ended up using your recommendation, and jesus, yep it's much easier! Does anyone use CBV's, or are they a bit like scaffolding in Rails? Good for basic stuff, but a bit crap overall? Thanks

Comment: Class based views are hard to get your head around at first, but lead to some really concise clean code. Also, the Admin seems to be based on the same concepts, so you will have far more ability to customise that once you understand them.

Comment: http://ccbv.co.uk/ should be required reading when using them.

Comment: Thanks. Updated question with what I ended up doing for future reference.

Comment: Just a comment about your updated code : the `context = {'form': SpaceForm, ...}` line doesn't populate your context with a `SpaceForm` instance but with the `SpaceForm` class.